# How to Clear the timer before running a Selector Function?

Tags: swift, xcode6, watchkit

I have a timer like this:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(time, target: self, selector: Selector("finished"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

with "time" is NSTimeInterval for running this timer, for example is 10.0 seconds. and "finished" is a function that running when timer is reach 10.0 seconds.
if my timer is running for example when my timer is reach 4.0 seconds, i want to clear or stop the timer or something like that and restart the timer again. How can i do that? I already tried to use:

```
timer.invalidate()
```

and recreate the timer again but it still call the "finished" function after that 6.0 seconds. 
Please help.

Comment: Calling `invalidate` is all that's needed.  Perhaps you're creating the timer more times than you think you are?  Post a minimum code set that demonstrates the problem you're encountering.

Comment: Thanks, I created the timer more times than I though!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var timer = NSTimer()
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func result() {
self.elapsedTime++

self.handler(elapsedTime)

if self.elapsedTime == self.duration {
  self.stop()
}
}

func stop() {
timer.invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem, I add more timer than I thought so the other timer still run and take my function.